# Serve a folder for a parameter

Tags: nginx, parameters, location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a question regarding parameter after root url:

```
URL is : https://test/?version=12.1.0
```

What I want there is a parameter starting with version=numner.number.number
To serve a folder under the root dir "v12.1.0"

```
location ~ ^\?version=v(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)  {
     root           /var/www/test/htdocs/v$2;

}
```

Is that possible? I've been trying wiith try files and root, but I cannot manage to make it work. Should I use map in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx normalises the URI before processing it. The part of the URI before the `?` is available as the `$uri` variable, and the part of the URI after the `?` is available as the `$args` variable.

The `location` and `rewrite` directives operate on the value of the `$uri` variable, so your present approach will not work, as the query string has already been remove.

The `$args` variable is further split into other individual variables, so that the value of your `version=` parameter is available as `$arg_version`.

---

One solution is to use a `map` block to decode `$arg_version` and use the mapped variable in a `try_files` statement as required.

For example:

```
map $arg_version $mypath {
    ~*^(v\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$ $1/;
    default              "";
}

server {
    ...

    root /var/www/test/htdocs;

    location ... {
        try_files $mypath$uri =404;
    }
}
```

We could use `$arg_version` as is, but the `map` ensures that the path prefix is sanitised and contains the necessary `/` separator.

Note that the `map` block lives outside of the `server` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

---

Depending on your specific requirements, you could also use the mapped variable directly with `root`. For example:

```
root /var/www/test/htdocs/$mypath;
```

Comment: Problem is that you stated a location. What I use the root location. There is already a root folder there, but I want only when passed that parameter to serve that nginx folder. Example> www.test.com > servers root folder, but if url is www.test.com?version=12.9.0 - server a folder inside the root directory. Is it possible?

Comment: That is exactly what my solution does. You probably only need to use the `root /var/www/test/htdocs/$mypath;` statement if the `version` trick is to apply to every URI.

Comment: But if I define root folder like this. Every other sub folders get ignored in the search and it search for a root folder with $mypath. The condition is ONLY if it has the parameter ?version=12.1.0 (example) for the rest it should go for root /var/www/test/htdocs/

Comment: If the `version` parameter is missing or anything other than `v.n.n.n`, the value of `$mypath` is an empty string - see the `default` clause.

Comment: I will test tommorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain me this part only ~*^(v\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$ $1/;

Comment: It's based on the regular expression in your question. If the parameter is `?version=12.1.0` (without the `v`) and the directory name is `v12.1.0`, then the correct line is `~^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$ v$1/;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237943/discussion-between-whoami-and-richard-smith).